# Having trouble aligning left elements and right elements on a navbar

Tags: html, css, alignment, navbar

I'm currently trying to make a navbar but I'm having trouble aligning my left and right containers. Currently, the right part is under the header container.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF6E3;
}

.left-nav-side {
  /* align-items: center;
        width: 30%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-top: 6%; */
  align-items: center;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.right-nav-side {
  float: right;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class='left-nav-side'>
    <img id='logo-image' src="images/cinnamon-roll.png" alt="">
    <h1 id="logo-title">BUN BUN BAKE SHOP</h1>
  </div>

  <div class='right-nav-side'>
    <ul>
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li><input type="button" id="button" value="Input Button"></li>
      <li><img id='logo-image' src="images/shopping-cart.png" alt=""></li>
      <li id='cart-number'>0</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Note that you can put HTML/CSS/JS embeds directly into your post. Muakes it much easier to see/debug. Just use the 'Javascript/HTML/Css snippet' button

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
header{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#FFF6E3;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

}
```

Long answer:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3ddad;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-nav-side {
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: flex;
}

.right-nav-side {
  margin-right: 5%;
  display: flex;
}

.right-nav-side ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  list-style: none;
}

.right-nav-side ul li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="left-nav-side">
      <img id="logo-image" src="images/cinnamon-roll.png" alt="" />
      <h1 id="logo-title">BUN BUN BAKE SHOP</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="right-nav-side">
      <ul>
        <li>About Us</li>
        <li><input type="button" id="button" value="Input Button" /></li>
        <li><img id="logo-image" src="images/shopping-cart.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li id="cart-number">0</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `display: flex;` to do what you want to do.

This sample will help you.

```css
#flex{
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: nowrap;
            }
            
            #left{
                width: 50%;
            }
            
            #right{
                width: 50%;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content = "ie=edge">
        <title> Keat </title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="flex">
            <div id="left">
            <h2>This is for left side</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
            <ul>
              <li>Link1</li>
              <li>Link2</li>
              <li>Link3</li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code is will be seperated by left and right. If you want to make some items float left and right you can use the display:flex; method. Otherwise it will be always be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried editing your code to achieve left and right alignment for left nav `<div>` and right nav `<div>`. Please check if this serves the purpose you were looking for.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF6E3;
  /* adding this may work */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  /* adding this may work */
}

.left-nav-side {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.right-nav-side {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  /* adding this may work */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  /* adding this may work */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class='left-nav-side'>
    <img id='logo-image' src="images/cinnamon-roll.png" alt="">
    <h1 id="logo-title">BUN BUN BAKE SHOP</h1>
  </div>

  <div class='right-nav-side'>
    <ul>
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li><input type="button" id="button" value="Input Button"></li>
      <li><img id='logo-image' src="images/shopping-cart.png" alt=""></li>
      <li id='cart-number'>0</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```